# Packaging Operation Failed while upgrading to 2023.3.3 Community Edition

Tags: pycharm

After upgrading to <Build #PC-233.11799.259, built on December 3, 2023>, File/Settings/myproject/Python Interpreter never llists packages. Line at the bottom of screen says <Python packaging tools not found. Install packaging tools>, while Notifications show <Packages installed successfully. Instwqalled Python packaging tools>.

Detailed packaging operation screen as follow:

```
Packaging Operation Failed

Executed command:
C:\Users\l...ya\Pycharm\Projection\Scripts\python.exe C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py list

Error occured:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Command output:
astroid 3.0.1   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages typing-extensions >=4.0.0 ; python_version < "3.11"
colorama    0.4.6   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 
contourpy   1.2.0   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages numpy<2.0,>=1.20:furo; extra == "docs":sphinx>=7.2; extra == "docs":sphinx-copybutton; extra == "docs":bokeh; extra == "bokeh":selenium; extra == "bokeh":contourpy[bokeh,docs]; extra == "mypy":docutils-stubs; extra == "mypy":mypy==1.6.1; extra == "mypy":types-Pillow; extra == "mypy":contourpy[test-no-images]; extra == "test":matplotlib; extra == "test":Pillow; extra == "test":pytest; extra == "test-no-images":pytest-cov; extra == "test-no-images":pytest-xdist; extra == "test-no-images":wurlitzer; extra == "test-no-images"
cycler  0.12.1  C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages ipython ; extra == 'docs':matplotlib ; extra == 'docs':numpydoc ; extra == 'docs':sphinx ; extra == 'docs':pytest ; extra == 'tests':pytest-cov ; extra == 'tests':pytest-xdist ; extra == 'tests'
dill    0.3.7   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages objgraph (>=1.7.2) ; extra == 'graph'
et-xmlfile  1.1.0   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 
fonttools   4.46.0  C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages fs <3,>=2.2.0 ; extra == 'all':lxml <5,>=4.0 ; extra == 'all':zopfli >=0.1.4 ; extra == 'all':lz4 >=1.7.4.2 ; extra == 'all':matplotlib ; extra == 'all':sympy ; extra == 'all':skia-pathops >=0.5.0 ; extra == 'all':uharfbuzz >=0.23.0 ; extra == 'all':brotlicffi >=0.8.0 ; (platform_python_implementation != "CPython") and extra == 'all':scipy ; (platform_python_implementation != "PyPy") and extra == 'all':brotli >=1.0.1 ; (platform_python_implementation == "CPython") and extra == 'all':munkres ; (platform_python_implementation == "PyPy") and extra == 'all':unicodedata2 >=15.1.0 ; (python_version <= "3.12") and extra == 'all':xattr ; (sys_platform == "darwin") and extra == 'all':lz4 >=1.7.4.2 ; extra == 'graphite':scipy ; (platform_python_implementation != "PyPy") and extra == 'interpolatable':munkres ; (platform_python_implementation == "PyPy") and extra == 'interpolatable':lxml <5,>=4.0 ; extra == 'lxml':skia-pathops >=0.5.0 ; extra == 'pathops':matplotlib ; extra == 'plot':uharfbuzz >=0.23.0 ; extra == 'repacker':sympy ; extra == 'symfont':xattr ; (sys_platform == "darwin") and extra == 'type1':fs <3,>=2.2.0 ; extra == 'ufo':unicodedata2 >=15.1.0 ; (python_version <= "3.12") and extra == 'unicode':zopfli >=0.1.4 ; extra == 'woff':brotlicffi >=0.8.0 ; (platform_python_implementation != "CPython") and extra == 'woff':brotli >=1.0.1 ; (platform_python_implementation == "CPython") and extra == 'woff'
future  0.18.3  C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 
isort   6.0.0b2 C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages colorama (>=0.4.3,<0.5.0) ; extra == "colors":pip-api ; extra == "requirements-deprecated-finder":pipreqs ; extra == "pipfile-deprecated-finder" or extra == "requirements-deprecated-finder":requirementslib ; extra == "pipfile-deprecated-finder":setuptools ; extra == "plugins"
kiwisolver  1.4.5   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages typing-extensions ; python_version < "3.8"
matplotlib  3.8.2   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages contourpy >=1.0.1:cycler >=0.10:fonttools >=4.22.0:kiwisolver >=1.3.1:numpy <2,>=1.21:packaging >=20.0:pillow >=8:pyparsing >=2.3.1:python-dateutil >=2.7:importlib-resources >=3.2.0 ; python_version<"3.10"
mccabe  0.7.0   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 
numexpr 2.8.7   C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages numpy >=1.13.3
numpy   1.26.2  C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 
openpyxl    3.2.0b1 C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages et-xmlfile
packaging   23.2    C:\Users\l...a\Pycharm\Projection\lib\site-packages 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 118, in main
    do_list()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 64, in do_list
    sys.stdout.write('\t'.join([pkg.name, pkg.version, str(pkg._path.parent), requires])+chr(10))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

I just don't know what else to try out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstall and install CE 2023-3 same problem persists. I rolled back to CE 2023.2.5. Now not up to date with PyCharm version, but problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

While I'm not entirely sure this is the general solution, it might be useful for other Windows user. Run the following script in your Python console and delete whatever is found to be broken:

```py
from importlib import metadata

for distribution in metadata.distributions():
  print(f'{distribution.name = }')

  if distribution.name is None:
    print(f'found broken distribution at {distribution._path}')
```

### How does that work?

As pointed out in another answer, these lines are where the error was found:

<sub>(from `PyCharm Community Edition 2023.x.y/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py`)</sub>

```py
import importlib.metadata
for pkg in importlib.metadata.distributions():
  try:
    requirements = [] if (pkg.requires is None) else pkg.requires
  except Exception:
    requirements = []
    requires = ':'.join([str(x) for x in requirements])
    sys.stdout.write('\t'.join([pkg.name, pkg.version, str(pkg._path.parent), requires])+chr(10))
```

The error means that the element at index 0 is not a `str`, but `None`: `pkg.name`. Note that this element is not changed directly by the code (which comes with PyCharm); it was emitted by [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html)`.distributions()`, a stdlib function.

Just to make sure, I ran this script in the Python console to verify my deductions:

```py
import importlib.metadata

for pkg in importlib.metadata.distributions():
    print([pkg, pkg.name, pkg.version])
```

...and indeed some of the distributions look like this:

```py
[<importlib.metadata.PathDistribution object at 0x0123456789ABCDEF>, None, None]
```

It can only emit such data if a distribution does not have a name, which is not the case for my package (I have `pyproject.toml` properly written), so it must have been someone else's fault. But who?

A quick search for `importlib.metadata.distributions None` led me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100455), from which I got the following script:

(credit goes to [DanAndersen](https://github.com/DanAndersen) via [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100455#issuecomment-1622625507))

```py
from importlib import metadata
ds = metadata.distributions()
for d in ds:
    print("===")
    print(d)
    print(f"{d.name=}")
    if d.name is None:
        print("FOUND")
        broken_dist = d
        print(f"found broken distribution at {d._path}")
        break
```

I ran it (with the Python console), and it was revealed that Windows was creating a directory of `distlib` whose name starts with `~` (which probably was meant to be a temporary one, but somehow persisted):

```
...
===
<importlib.metadata.PathDistribution object at 0x0123456789ABCDEF>
d.name=None
FOUND
found broken distribution at <CWD>\venv\lib\site-packages\~istlib-0.3.8.dist-info
```

In the progress, I also realized that a distribution (mine) was registered multiple times. Running the same script but with `d.name == 'my-pkg-name'`, I found out that the `.egg-info` directory was also broken. I deleted both directories manually, and everything was fine again.

Comment: Just found your solution, works for me perfectly. Thanks for investigating and giving such a detailed answer mate.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is due to the fact that one of the elements in the list you are trying to join with '\t'.join(...) is of type NoneType. Specifically, it seems that pkg.version or requires is None in one of the iterations.

To fix this issue, you should check for None values before trying to concatenate them into a string. You can use the str() function to convert them to strings safely - C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py Line 64. Change this line to this and it should work:

```
sys.stdout.write('\t'.join([str(pkg.name), str(pkg.version), str(pkg._path.parent), str(requires)]) + chr(10))
```

By using str() for each element, you ensure that even if any of them is None, it will be converted to the string representation, preventing the TypeError.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately the command reported on Traceback as line 118 in main is triggered by Pycharm when accessing Settings/Project/Python Interpreter. I cannot control the execution.

Comment: Performed uninstall/install Pycharm, deleting caches and other: same problem. My next step will be to uninstall/install Python3 as well.

Comment: In my case it work perfectly. Just eited line 64 and added str() conversion.